# Can I use Xcode 4.2?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

Can I use the new Xcode 4.2 to make apps for older version of the iOS? Will they work?
I like the new features like the Storyboard and Automatic Reference Counting.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a specific issue of tooling.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode), yes you can:

"Xcode 4.0 drops support for many older systems, including all PowerPC development as well as SDKs for 10.4 and 10.5, and all iOS SDKs older than 4.3. **The deployment target can still be set to produce binaries for those older platforms**, however for Mac OS X applications only x86 and x86_64 binaries can be produced."